# Erro ao formatar CEP

Tags: javascript

Estou com problemas no meu script, quando o campo CEP já está formatado, ele limpa o campo ao clicar novamente no botão. Como faço para ele não acusar como formato inválido ou não limpar o campo quando já estiver formatado?

**Script**

```js
window.onload=function(){
 document.getElementById("botao").onclick=function(){
  var strCEP = document.getElementById("cep").value;

  cep.value = formatarCEP(strCEP);
 }
}

function formatarCEP(str){
 var re = /^([\d]{2})([\d]{3})([\d]{3})|^[\d]{2}.[\d]{3}-[\d]{3}/;

 if(re.test(str)){
  return str.replace(re,"$1.$2-$3");
 }else{
  alert("CEP inválido!");
 }
 
 return "";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>Página Teste</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div>
   <label for="cep">CEP: <input type="text" id="cep" maxlength="8" /></label>
  </div>
  <p>
   <button id="botao">Testar</button>
  </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema está na sua RegEx:

```
/^([\d]{2})([\d]{3})([\d]{3})|^[\d]{2}.[\d]{3}-[\d]{3}/
```

Quando há só dígitos, os grupos de captura $1, $2 e $3 são pegos pelos parênteses, na condição antes do `|`:

```
/^([\d]{2})([\d]{3})([\d]{3})/
     $1       $2       $3
```

Porém, com o número formatado, você cai nesta parte da RegEx:

```
/^[\d]{2}.[\d]{3}-[\d]{3}/
```

que não tem grupo nenhum, portanto $1, $2 e $2 são vazios.

Pegando as duas condições, mesclei em uma só, tornando o ponto e o traço opcionais, através do operador `*`. Veja abaixo:

```js
window.onload=function(){
 document.getElementById("botao").onclick=function(){
  var strCEP = document.getElementById("cep").value;

  cep.value = formatarCEP(strCEP);
 }
}

function formatarCEP(str){
 var re = /^([\d]{2})\.*([\d]{3})-*([\d]{3})/; // Pode usar ? no lugar do *

 if(re.test(str)){
  return str.replace(re,"$1.$2-$3");
 }else{
  alert("CEP inválido!");
 }
 
 return "";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>Página Teste</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div>
   <label for="cep">CEP: <input type="text" id="cep" maxlength="8" /></label>
  </div>
  <p>
   <button id="botao">Testar</button>
  </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Importante notar que este uso da RegEx é muito limitado. Eu provavelmente no seu lugar trabalharia nestes pontos:

1. Aceitasse mais caracteres no campo, facilitando a vida do usuário ao usar *copy & paste*, que muitas vezes vem com espaços a mais, e caracteres indevidos.
2. Descartasse todo caractere que não é dígito, já que vai ser formatado de qualquer forma.
3. Não usaria RegEx. RegEx é um recurso que serve quando as soluções mais simples não resolvem. No seu caso, pode-se resolver com operações de string.

Comment: Bacco eu gostei do seu exemplo. Muito bom, a minha intensão seria usar as duas RegEx e comparar usando o "|", mas nem me passou na cabeça de usar o "*". Obrigada pela ajuda!

Answer (score 2):

Altera a expressão regular para essa forma:

```
/^([\d]{2})\.?([\d]{3})\-?([\d]{3})/
```

Onde a metacaractere ? indica nessa expressão que a existência dos caracteres . e - não são obrigatorios para validação da mesma, e sim são opcionais, com ocorrencia de zero ou um caracter.

Você também poderia usar dessa forma abaixo com a metacaracter *, funcionaria, mas teria um pequeno erro, onde CEP's tais como esse 11...000---000 também seram válidos, pois o metacaracter quantificador * verifica ser a String tem a ocorrencia de zero o mais caracteres.

No seu trecho de código não ser percebe esse erro por causa da limitação de caracteres do input text.

```
/^([\d]{2})\.*([\d]{3})\-*([\d]{3})/
```

```js
window.onload=function(){
 document.getElementById("botao").onclick=function(){
  var strCEP = document.getElementById("cep").value;

  cep.value = formatarCEP(strCEP);
 }
}

function formatarCEP(str){
 var re = /^([\d]{2})\.?([\d]{3})\-?([\d]{3})/;

 if(re.test(str)){
  return str.replace(re,"$1.$2-$3");
 }else{
  alert("CEP inválido!");
 }
 
 return '';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>Página Teste</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div>
   <label for="cep">CEP: <input type="text" id="cep" maxlength="8" /></label>
  </div>
  <p>
   <button id="botao">Testar</button>
  </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yure, achei legal a sua troca dos quantificadores. Na verdade eu vi esse erro que você comentou, mas não sabia como resolvê-lo. Obrigada pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

segue a validacao do cep em JQUERY

----------HTML

```
<div>
            <label for="cep">CEP: <input type="text" id="cep" ></label>
        </div>
        <p>
            <button id="botao">Testar</button>
        </p>
```

------------SCRIPT

```
function validarCep()
{
    var patt = new RegExp(/^([\d]{2})([\d]{3})([\d]{3})|^[\d]{2}.[\d]{3}-[\d]{3}/);
    str = $('#cep').val();    
    var res = patt.test(str);    

    if (!res)    
    {
        alert(res);   
        return false;
    }else{


        return true;    
        }
}

$("#botao").click(function(event) {

var ok = validarCep();

    if (ok == true)
    {
        alert("CEP VALIDO. ESCREVA SEU CODIGO AQUI............");
    }

});
```

Comment: Leandro eu gostei do seu exemplo, é bem prático. Vou deixar guardado em favoritos para projetos que eu usar o jQuery. Fica bem simples e objetivo. Obrigada!